# Read a line and pass each word as an argument

Tags: bash, shell

I have file as below

```
ABC  v1.2.3 

PQRS v4.5 

XYZ v2.0
```

I want to read each the whole line and cut them into individual strings and pass that as an argument to another script. How can i achieve this using bash shell scripting.

Expected Output:

```
bash test.sh ABC v1.2.3
```

Comment: This is [a dup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149726/how-to-pass-each-line-of-a-text-file-as-an-argument-to-a-command).

Answer (score 3):

Read each line into an array first.

```
while read -r -a args; do
    bash test.sh "${args[@]}"
done < args.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with `xargs` command line:

```
<params xargs -l test.sh
```

And with a test.sh like:

```
echo $0
echo $1
echo $2
```

The output is:

```
./test.sh
ABC
v1.2.3
./test.sh
PQRS
v4.5
./test.sh
XYZ
v2.0
```

And there is an online tester: [Tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMczY1VTJkdmNDejg)

Answer (score 1):

Umm have you tried-

```
while read -r line ; do test.sh $line ; done < file
```

The `while` loop reads the file (indicated at the end with `< file`) line by line.

Then it's just a matter of using the line stored in `$line` as you need. In your case, as an argument to `test.sh`.

Comment: If you want to pass each word as a separate argument, you cannot double quote `$line` variable: `... do test.sh $line ; ...`. Then you could double quotes to pass multi-word parameters.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaszkowiak, good catch. This is one place where you **need** globbing due to the unquoted variable. Edited.

Comment: You need word-splitting, not globbing. Globbing could actually be a problem; if any special characters like `*` or `?` occur in the input, they could expand to one or more matching files when `$line` is expanded unquoted.